# Deborphan - Verify That a Package in the Keep List Is an Orphan

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dependencies

How does one quickly verify that a Debian package in the **deborphan** "Keep List" is an orphan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deborphan -nk /dev/null $(package name)`

A *single* line of output, parroting said package name, verifies that said package is, indeed, an orphan. e.g. the following return indicates that the package **bar** is an orphan:

```
user@host:~$ deborphan -nk /dev/null $packagename
$packagename
```

To get a list of ALL "false orphans":

```
while read i; do a=$(deborphan -nk /dev/null $i) ; if [ "$a" != "$i" ]; then echo "$i" ; fi; done </var/lib/deborphan/keep
```

Since a corrupted line in said **/var/lib/deborphan/keep** file can screw up the script, recommend you peruse the list first, looking for signs of trouble:

```
deborphan -L
```